# Connection failed with PSQL on Android App Studio

Tags: java, android, sql, postgresql

I had a Java app that worked perfectly and I'm trying now to convert it to Android.
Before converting to android the connection with the database worked, but now it's just not connecting and I have no idea why.

I know that having PSQL connect to a db on Android is not safe at all but it's a small personal app.

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        final String URL = "my server";
        final String USERNAME = "user";
        final String PASSWORD = "pas";

.>272           Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

Errors:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
>
> at com.example.loto6din49.DatabaseMethods.dropWinningNumbers(DatabaseMethods.java:272)
>
> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission
>   denied)

If there is any more info I should give, please reply with a comment.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I added some permissions in the manifests

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

The errors I get now are:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
>   W/System.err:     at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:277)
>   Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by adding the permissions to the manifests

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

And after that, for the Driver errors the fix was this:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Explanation : "To use jdbc on Android it is necessary to use the StrictMode. That can be done by using the following code lines:"